# How to find height and width of element passed to Directive's link function in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I cannot find the height or width of the element passed to the 'link' function. I need it because I want to calculate the position of a mouse click on an image appended to the element. <del>offsetHeight, offsetWidth, clientHeight and clientWidth are all undefined, and so are the x and y in position. getBoundingClientRect throws a 'not a function' error.</del> Setting height and width attributes in the template doesn't change anything.

Here is a simple directive that illustrates the problem:

> ```
> //OLD
> var ngnDirectives = angular.module('ngnDirectives');
>
> ngnDirectives.directive('positionTest', function() {
>
>     function link(scope, element, attrs) {
>
>
>   console.log("POSITION");
>     var position = element.position();
>     for(p in position) {
>         console.log(p + ", " + element[p]);
>     }
>     console.log("END POSITION");
>     var offset = element.offset();
>     console.log("element.offset x, y: " + offset.left + ", " + offset.top);
>     console.log("offsetWidth, offsetHeight: " + element.offsetWidth + ", " + element.offsetHeight);
>     console.log("clientWidth, clientHeight: " + element.clientWidth + ", " + element.clientHeight);
>     //get BoundingClientRect throws 'not a function' error
>     console.log("getBoundingClientRect: " + element.getBoundingClientRect()); 
>
>     }
>     return {
>         scope: {},
>         restrict: 'E',
>         template: '<div></div>',
>         link: link
>
>     };
> });
> ```

## UPDATE

After getting the comment that `element[0]` is the raw DOM element, I found that `offsetWidth`, `offsetHeight`, `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` still don't return values I understand. I changed the code to use `getBoundingClientRect`, and found that it does not return a correct 'bottom' for the figure. Here is the code:

```
//NEW
var ngnDirectives = angular.module('ngnDirectives');

ngnDirectives.directive('positionTest', function() {

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {


    var bcr = element[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log("bcr before css. left, right, top, bottom: " + bcr.left + ", " + bcr.right + ", " + bcr.top + ", " + bcr.bottom); 


    element.css("height", 217);
    element.css("width", 217);


    bcr = element[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log("bcr after css. left, right, top, bottom: " + bcr.left + ", " + bcr.right + ", " + bcr.top + ", " + bcr.bottom); 


    console.log("offsetWidth, offsetHeight: " + element[0].offsetWidth + ", " + element[0].offsetHeight);
    console.log("clientWidth, clientHeight: " + element[0].clientWidth + ", " + element[0].clientHeight);

    }
    return {
        scope: {},
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div></div>',
        link: link

    };
});
```

Comment: The raw DOM element is `element[0]`. The `element` argument revealed to the link function is a [jqLite wrapper](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angularjs-s-jqlite) for the DOM element.

Comment: I am loading jQuery before Angular, so I can expect the wrapper to be a jQuery wrapper, right?

Comment: If jQuery is available, Angular use the jQuery function. If jQuery is not available, the framework delegates to AngularJS's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or [**jqLite.**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angularjs-s-jqlite)

Comment: Likely the framework hasn't rendered all of the DOM at that point. Add [$timeout delay](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) to see.

Comment: If you want position, maybe you should get top/left attributes, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was not getting the height and width from the correct element. On entering the link function, I append an svg tag to the element. The svg tag has width and height, and using getClientBoundingRect on that tag works. However, element[0] is a  tag which comes from the directive's 'template:' definition (an empty div). So the element beginning the directive in the template looks like this:

```
>...<div></div><svg>...</svg><
```

Appending the svg tag to the  element results in displaying the string literal representation of the svg tag, which I could probably fix, but it also works to simply select the svg child of the element passed in to the link function.